# How to hide items of listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to develop an app in which i need to create a list which contain many items.
There is also some button represent categories , and i want to populate my list according to the category.

For example: if there are 10 items in the list out of which item 1,5,7,8 are belongs to 1st category and rest of them belongs to 2nd category,now if user press 1st category button then listview show items belonging to 1st category only.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use an ExpandableListView for showing a 2 level hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

I think [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) will work for you. Refer this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be able to filter (hide/show) items in a `ListView` you can use an adapter, for example by creating your own implementation of `BaseAdapter`. This adapter has methods for sorting, clearing and adding elements to the dataset used by your `ListView`, as stated in [this list tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_adapterintro). Just remember to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've altered the dataset to refresh the `ListView`.

Setup example:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new MyAdapter(...); // Probably send along data
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Filter example:

```
int[] newData = { 1, 5, 7, 8 };
adapter.clear();
for(int i : newData)
    adapter.add(i);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide item in list (remove from list) before you set adapter. When your list is ready set notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter